# "save_post" hook not working on post type attachment

Tags: php, wordpress

I am making use of the "[SEO Ultimate](http://wordpress.org/plugins/seo-ultimate/)" plugin for the seo purpose. The meta box is working fine for the `post_type = post`. But as I am saving the meta details for the `post_type = attachment` then it's not working. It just leaves the field blank after saving the details.

After research on the plugin, I found a function name `save_postmeta_box` which is hooked with `save_post`. I thinks there is a problem with the hook which doesn't work on `post_type = attachment`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a research on the hook's, I got the solution for this error, you just need to add a attachment hook. And the plugin will work fine for `post_type=attachment`.

Go to the line no. 227 "http://hostname.com/wp-content/plugin/seo-ultimate/plugin/class.seo-ultimate.php" and add this code below as given here:

```
add_action('edit_attachment', array ( &$this, 'save_postmeta_box'));
```

Now you can add the meta details on the meta boxes.